# Find a condition under $n$ such that the error $R_n$ in approximating the sum of the serie by $s_n$ is less than $10^{-3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n^2+1}$$

I have no idea of how to solve this problem, I know that theorem for alternating series, $|R_n| = |S-S_n|$ $\le$ $a_{n+1}$

How am I going to find $n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to find $n$ such that:
$$\frac{1}{n^2+1} \le 10^{-3}$$ which is equivalent to $n^2 + 1 \ge 10^3$. $n \ge 32$ would be good.

Comment: If the series is not alternating how could I solve ? ex: $1/n^3$

Comment: A way is to compare the reminder of the series with an integral.

Comment: could you please show how to do this ?

Comment: Please Google comparison series vs. integral.

Comment: I found nothing relevant to the problem

Answer (score 1):

In the sum of 
an alternating series
with decreasing terms,
the error at any point
is less than the
last term used.

So,
as mathcounterexamples.net
wrote,
it is enough if
$\dfrac1{n^2+1}
\le .001
$,
and
$n=32$ will do.